# buidling Tic Tac Toe, Why my method is not working?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build a Tic Tac Toe, the method `valid_move?` suppose to make sure the submitted position is:

1. Present on the game board.
2. Not already filled with a token.

So I first tried to make sure the position is between 1-9 on the board, and second tried to make sure the position is not taken, here i just use a **helper method** `position_taken?` but seems something is wrong and my `valid_move?` is not working....

```
def valid_move?(board,position)
  if  position.to_i.between?(1,9) && position_taken?
    true
  else
     false
  end
end



def position_taken?(board,position)
  if board[position] == " "
    false
    elsif board[position] == ""
    false
    elsif  board[position] == nil
    false
    else   board[position] == "X" || "O"
    true

  end
end
```

basically im trying to pass below spec:

```
  it 'returns true for a valid position on an empty board' do
    board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
    position = "1"
    expect(valid_move?(board, position)).to be_truthy
  end

  it 'returns nil or false for an occupied position' do
    board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " "]
    position = "5"

    expect(valid_move?(board, position)).to be_falsey
  end

  it 'returns nil or false for a position that is not on the board' do 
    board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
    position = 100

    expect(valid_move?(board, position)).to be_falsey
  end

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `and not position_taken?` instead of `and position_taken?`?

Comment: It should also be `board[position] == "X" || board[position] == "O"`

Comment: i tried !position_taken? not working either

Comment: I've made some changes, I'll post them in a sec

Comment: Don't you need to pass the parameters?    position_taken?(board,position)

Comment: What is an example of what `board` can be?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 It's probably just an array with the positions from say 1 to 9 which would yield a 3x3 board.

Comment: yes oleander is right

Comment: @Danny Note that the indexes in Ruby starts at `0` not `1` (in contrast to mathlab).

Comment: @Oleander yes, my problem right now is actually the second part, how to make sure the board Not already filled with a token

Comment: I think it's time that you post all your code

Comment: Posting the specs was a good move. I just ran them on my code and everything is passing. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how your code is suppose to work, but here are some things that caught my mind.

You can't have a condition after `else`, so `else board[position] == "X" || "O"` wont work. Even if you used `elseif board[position] == "X" || "O"`, it would always return true as `"0"` is truthy. `board[position] == "X" || board[position] == "O"` would be more correct.

You didn't pass any args to `position_taken?` and from the looks of it should be inverted, meaning you should negate it's value. I mean, it's only a valid move *unless* the position is taken.

Your specs are also assumes that board position `1` is at index `1`, which isn't correct. You've to decrement the value by `1` to make it work, like `position.to_i - 1`.

Try this.

```
def valid_move?(board,position)
  position.to_i.between?(1,9) and not position_taken?(board, position.to_i - 1)
end

def position_taken?(board,position)
  return false if [" ", "", nil].include?(board[position])
  return true if ["X", "O"].include?(board[position])
  raise "#{board[position]} is not a valid move"
end
```

Comment: it's not working , position_taken? is a helper method in ruby, so i dont think you need to pass any arguments ...

Comment: No, the method doesn't exist it Ruby. Why would there be a method to check if a position is taken on a Tic Tac Toe board :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write:

```
board[position] == "X" || "O"
```

Here's some things to consider:

If the board position is `''`:

```
[2] (pry) main: 0> '' == 'X' || 'O'
"O"
```

If the board position is `' '`:

```
[3] (pry) main: 0> ' ' == 'X' || 'O'
"O"
```

If the board position is `'X'`:

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> 'X' == 'X' || 'O'
true
```

If the board position is `'O'`:

```
[5] (pry) main: 0> 'O' == 'X' || 'O'
"O"
```

In other words, you want a true/false, however you're not getting one. This is because Ruby is comparing `'' == 'X'`, THEN checking `'O'` and returning it because `'O'` is a truthy value.

Try:

```
board[position] == "X" || board[position] == "O"
```

This is untested but you should be able to use:

```
def position_taken?(board,position)
  board[position] == "X" || board[position] == "O"
end
```

or

```
def position_taken?(board,position)
  !!board[position][/^[XO]$/]
end
```

Comment: You *can* write that, it just won't do what you're thinking it will do. It will check to see if board[position] is true.

Comment: the 'position_taken?' methoid is actually working ,but 'valid_move?' is not

Comment: Your 'position_taken?' method won't work the way you think it does. That's the point of the first statement; your logic is wrong.